# django jquery ajax Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json

Tags: jquery, python, json, ajax, django

I have an html page which display a list of products with each product having an add to cart button.

my html view:

```
 {% for sku, name, mrp, sp, id in product_data_list %}
      <form id="add_to_cart" action="{% url 'add_to_cart' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="item">
          <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="item-img">
              <div class="item-img-info"><a href="product-detail.html" title="{{name}}" class="product-image"><img src="{% static "products-images/p1.jpg" %}" alt="Retis lapen casen"></a>
                <div class="item-box-hover">
                  <div class="box-inner">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item-info">
              <div class="info-inner">
                <div class="item-title"><a href="product-detail.html" title="{{name}}">{{name}}</a> </div>
                  <div class="item-content">
                    <div class="rating">
                      <div class="ratings">
                        <div class="rating-box">
                          <div class="rating" style="width:80%"></div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="rating-links"><a href="#">1 Review(s)</a> <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="#">Add Review</a> </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-price">
                      <div class="price-box"><span class="regular-price" id="product-price-1"><s><span class="price"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>&nbsp;{{mrp}}</span></s>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="regular-price" id="product-price-1"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>&nbsp;{{sp}}</span> </span> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="add_cart">
                      <button class="button btn-cart" type="submit" id="product_id" value="{{id}}"><span>Add to Cart</span></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        {% endfor %}
```

The above code displays product data from the data base.
 I am using ajax requests to POST data back to django view.

My ajax script:

```
<script>

  jQuery(document).ready(function($){$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
      if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
      }
    }
  });});

  jQuery(document).ready(function($){$('#add_to_cart').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url : "/add_to_cart/", // the endpoint
        type : "POST",
        cache: false,
        async: "true",
        data : { product_id : $('#product_id').val()}, // data sent with the post request

    // handle a successful response
        success : function(json) {
            // $('#product_id').val(''); 
            console.log("success"); // another sanity check
            alert("Product Added To Cart.")
        },

     // handle a non-successful response
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(errmsg);
            }
    });
  });});
</script>
```

My django view:

```
def addToCart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response_data = {}
        product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')

        try:
            try:
                cart = request.COOKIES.get('cart')
                cart = cart + '*' + product_id
                response_data['result'] = 'Added To Cart Successfully !!!'
                response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),content_type="application/json")
                response.set_cookie('cart',cart)
            except:
                cart = product_id
                response_data['result'] = 'Added To Cart Successfully !!!'
                response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),content_type="application/json")
                response.set_cookie('cart',cart)
        except:
            response_data['result'] = 'Cannot Be Added To Cart !!!'

        return response
    else:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"result": "Failure !!!"}),content_type="application/json")
```

This code works fine and it adds the data(product_id) to the cookie with variable cart.
The problem is that if my html template renders more than one item or product, the ajax request works only for the for the first item only and for rest of the products it adds `None` instead of the `product id`. Also it navigates to the page `localhost:8000/add_to_cart` and displays a dict `{'result':'Added To Cart Successfully !!!'}`. While for first product it stays on the same page without refreshing.
How to make it work for all the items?

EDIT: In console it says:

Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple elements in your HTML code with same `id`, and that template code will create it that way. Use:

```
<form id="add_to_cart_{{ forloop.index }}" class="add_to_cart_form" action="{% url 'add_to_cart' %}" method="POST">
```

instead (also fix any other elements with same `id`s) and change in your javascript code:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){$('add_to_cart_form').on('submit', function(event){
```

and

```
$(this).find('.product_id').val()
```

Comment: Now its not passing any value back to view. I checked in console and it is passing none